# what is RSpec in context to Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have read Rspec from RubyonRails Tutorial 3 book. But i am actually not getting the language what it is trying to explain.Please can  anyone explain me in simple way for easy understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

At its core, RSpec is just a ruby library for automated testing, just like Test::Unit or Minitest. The thing with RSpec is that it uses very special syntax and method names to make the test code read like english prose. This is done to give the reader a better understanding of the test code and make it easier to read, although whether RSpec achieves this is controversial and highly subjective.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble understanding RSpec, I recommend [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#top). It teaches RSpec as part of regular Ruby on Rails development.

What I understand so far is that RSpec (and test-driven development in general) is a method of developing programs while ensuring that the program does what you want it to do. The process is three-part:

1. Write a test to test for a new feature. The test will fail because you haven't written the code yet.
2. Write the code for the new feature.
3. Run the test and modify the code until the test passes.